# PHP include function distorting page?

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to make a backend login panel that uses include methods to load pages but for some reason it's completely distorting it.
This is what it's supposed to look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1iub.png

The url for this is /dashboard/dashboard.php

But then when I try to use include('dashboard/dashboard.php'); I get this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzJz8.png

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please show some code, we can't guess what's happening here. Have a look at the source code obtained: is there any `div` tag not closed at the right place for example, or something like that?

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to tell what you mean without seeing some code. If I had to guess it appears to be an issue with float. As in the left menu is floated left and the width of that plus the dashboard element is wider than your screen causing it to wrap down.

Comment: Here's the source code: http://pastebin.com/dZLC4zkA. It's logically sound when opened by itself (i.e. going to www.site.com/dashboard/dashboard.php), but using the include function breaks it and shifts it down.

Comment: This is the code for the login page, not the dashboard?

Comment: Yes, that's the login. Here's the dashboard (had the wrong url copied, sorry).  http://pastebin.com/BTFtFseH

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any error in your include code but when we're going to include a file in another file then we need to give the path for file's directory. In your case I didn't see this. Please use

```
include('./dashboard/dashboard.php'); //For the same directory
```

OR

```
include('../dashboard/dashboard.php'); // For one directory back
```

It may work..

Comment: Both of them work loading the page, but it's still distorted. I made sure the path was correct beforehand.